# IllegalAccessError when running Unit Test with EMMA for Android app

Tags: android, unit-testing, emma

Why am I getting a IllegalAccessError when trying to run my test project with code coverage?

I get the following error when running ant.

```
host:MyAppTest mach$ ant clean emma instrument install test

 [...]

 [echo] Running tests ...
 [exec] 
 [exec] com.example.myapp.test.MyClassTest:.
 [exec] Error in testMyMethod:
 [exec] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 [exec]     at com.example.myapp.test.MyClassTest.testMyMethod(MyClassTest.java:10)
 [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 [exec]     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
 [exec]     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
 [exec]     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
 [exec]     at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
 [exec] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
 [exec]     at com.example.myapp.MyClass.$VRi(MyClass.java)
 [exec]     at com.example.myapp.MyClass.<clinit>(MyClass.java)
 [exec]     ... 13 more
```

I have a class in my App

```
public class MyClass {
    public boolean myMethod(int i) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And a test class in my Test App

```
public class MyClassTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    public void testMyMethod() {
        MyClass a = new MyClass();  // <--- THIS MAKES THE TEST FAIL
                                    // If I remove this line it runs
                                    // successfully but does not test anything...
    }
}
```

I have created my two ant build.xml with the following parameters

```
host:MyApp mach$ android update project --path $PWD --name MyApp --target android-16 --subprojects

host:MyAppTest mach$ android update test-project --main ../MyApp --path ./
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - I tried to instrument the unit test as well.

So here is the short version of successfully building a Unit test and getting code coverage

In Eclipse, for your project, open Properties->Java Build Path and select the "Libraries"-tab. Press "Add External JARs..." and select emma.jar form your SDK.([...]/sdk/tools/lib/emma.jar)

Select the "Order and Export" tab and select to export emma.jar.

Open a terminal and change directory to the root of your project-to-be-tested.

```
android update project --path $PWD --name [YOUR PROJECT NAME] --target android-17 --subprojects
```

Create a test project.

```
android create test-project -m ../ -n MyAppTest -p tests
```

Write your test cases in the new test project

When it is time to test first build a instrumented build of the project-to-be-tested and then build and execute the tests

```
ant clean instrument
cd tests
ant debug emma install test
```

You will find the coverage report in tests/bin

Cheers!